# check a checkbox with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to check and uncheck a check box. this is my html code.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="isWorking" name="isWorking" />
```

i tried to do it with jquery this way,

```
$('#isWorking').val('1');
$('#isWorking').val('0');
```

How can I control checkboxes with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.prop` method.

```
$('#isWorking').prop('checked', true);  // check it
$('#isWorking').prop('checked', false); // uncheck it
```

Comment: why use prop method instead of attr?

Comment: @lttyhead Because it is a property over attribute.

Comment: The OP is targeting to id thus attr would be better way.

Comment: @C-link What do you mean by `targeting to id`?

Answer (score 1):

For set Checkbox value you need to use **.prop**

```
$('#isWorking').prop('checked', true);
$('#isWorking').prop('checked', false);
```

[Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/awJXM/1/

**JS:-**

```
$('#isWorking').attr("checked",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this,

```
$("#isWorking").attr('checked', true);
```

to see if a checkbox is checked or not:

```
$('#isWorking').is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `attr`

```
$('#isWorking').attr('checked', true);
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
 $('#isWorking').prop('checked', true/false);
```

A good read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#isWorking").prop("checked",true); //check
$("#isWorking").prop("checked",false); //uncheck
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `.prop()` is recommended now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#isWorking").attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: `.prop()` is recommended now.